# Sql server looping records

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a query for an insurance application and it has insurance plans. Let’s say PlanA, PlanB, PlanC, PlanD

The insurance plans are in the database and I can fetch them directly using a select query.

```
Select PlanName as [Plan], ‘’ as Section from app.[Plan]
```

Now i have few sections which are not in any table in the database ‘Protective’, ‘Effective’, ‘EasyClaim’.

Each plan has these 3 sections and for each plan I want to have these 3 sections.

If there are 3 plans then my query needs to return 12 records as below

```
PlanA Protective
PlanA Effective
PlanA EasyClaim
PlanB Protective
```

One way I could think of is create a temporary table in my proc and store these 3 sections in that temporary table and do a left join with that temporary table, any better suggestions?

Comment: Fix your schema - nothing should be assumed. If you don't want them in a table, then put them in a view. Why? Because eventually something about them will change. In a table or view there is only one place to change them rather than every bit of code where you needed to refer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need a `VALUES` table construct, if I understand
what you are saying correctly:

```sql
SELECT P.PlanName
       V.Section
FROM app.Plan P
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Protective'),('Effective'),('EasyClaim'))V(Section);
```

Comment: Hey Larnu thank you for sparing your time, I have 6 plans and 4 sections in total but the cross apply has resulted in 200 records... It should actually return 24 records 6(plans) * 4(sections)... sorry for incomplete query due to company policy I did not post complete query, my query has few more joins do you think that’s causing the issue ?

Comment: Then you've done something wrong, @Sayan . If the table `app.Plan` only has `6` **rows** (tables don't have "records") that query can only produce 24 **rows**. It's impossible for it to create more.

Comment: There was issue with the joins, it’s now resolved